# Sizing issues with glyphicon in href link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the glyphicon to fill the whole grey area, but can't manage to get it to do it, it appears in the top left corner and it's tiny, any help?

[How it looks right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myfsv.png)

```css
.back-to-top {     
  background: none;     
  margin: 0;     
  position: fixed;     
  bottom: 30px;     
  right: 30px;     
  width: 70px;     
  height: 70px;     
  z-index: 100;     
  display: 0;     
  text-decoration: none;     
  color: #ffffff;    
  background-color: #797979; 
}         

back-to-top i {     
  font-size: 60px     
}

footer {
  padding: 50px
}
```

```html
<footer>    
    <a href="#" class="back-to-top" style="display: inline;">     
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up"></span>
    </a>   
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add styling to the span for the icon with font-size equal to the size of your container.

```
<footer>    
    <a href="#" class="back-to-top" style="display: inline;">     
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up" style="font-size: 70px;"></span>
    </a>   
</footer>
```

However, I would recommend creating a class for the span and moving the inline style to the external style sheet.